# How to bind button Name to Content?

Tags: wpf, binding

I have a list of buttons:

```
  <Button Style="{DynamicResource DestinationButtonStyle}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FullName}"
                               Style="{DynamicResource DestinationStationTextBlockStyle}"
                               TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" />
                </Button>
```

I want buttons to have names equal to text of content.
Is it possible to make this kind of binding?

Comment: Are you talking about `Name` property of `Button` class?

Comment: Yes, I mean the Name property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote from the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.name.aspx):

> Data binding a Name is technically possible, but is an extremely uncommon scenario because a data-bound Name cannot serve the main intended purpose of the property: to provide an identifier connection point for code-behind.

In short, the `Binding` Name property for control is impossible and undesirable. But you can use the attached dependency property, like this:

```
<Button local:GiveName.Name="{Binding FullName}" ... />
```

Or you can use the `Tag` of `Button`, for `Tag` Binding works.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't do that. There are several restrictions for `Name` property. [As MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.name.aspx):

> Data binding a Name is technically possible, but is an extremely
>   uncommon scenario because a data-bound Name cannot serve the main
>   intended purpose of the property: to provide an identifier connection
>   point for code-behind.