# Windows phone 8.1 LongListSelector issue with button

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

I implemented `LongListSelector` controller instead of `ListView` contoller because I am using Windows Phone Silverlight Application.

I want to bind Name to the `Button` controller. But I am unable to complete it.

```
<Button  Name="{Binding Name}" Content="Download" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Click="Button_Click_1" Width="170" Height="70" Background="#b3c833"></Button>
```

I succeed for `TextBox` and `Image` for `LongListSelector` controller.

Any advise would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class Station
{
    //  private string _stationName;

    private string _stationName;
    //  private BitmapImage bm = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Image/Darktheme.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    private Uri bm;
    private string btnop;
    public Uri ImageUrl
    {
        get { return bm; }
        set { bm = value; }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _stationName; }
        set { _stationName = value; }
    }
    public string btnop1
    {
        get { return btnop; }
        set {
            btnop = value; }
    }
    public Station( Uri bm,string station, string ty)
    {
        this.Name = station;
    this.ImageUrl = bm;
        this.btnop1 = ty;
    }
}


ObservableCollection<Station> trainStations = new ObservableCollection<Station>();
trainStations.Add(new Station(new Uri("Assets/pdfdoc.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute),d, word));
```

Comment: Can you please add code snippets of what you have done?

Comment: <Button  Name="{Binding Name}" Content="Download" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Click="Button_Click_1" Width="170" Height="70" Background="#b3c833"></Button>

Comment: Instead of binding x:Name, Try using `Tag` property of silverlight. For example Tag = "{Binding Title}"

Comment: What error do you get? Are you trying to access the bound member from `C#`?

Comment: It can be an issue of DataContext. Are you sure the button has the right DataContext?

Comment: It is blocking the screen..

Comment: I am new to windows phone 8.1 development.  So i i am assigning proper value to the button name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `FrameworkElement.Tag` property, according to MSDN.

**FrameworkElement.Tag gets or sets an arbitrary object value that can be used to store custom information about this element.**

This [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19225437/binding-a-controls-xname) states clearly. Binding can be done only to `DependencyProperty`. It cannot work on `x:Name`.

If you want to iterate through the `LongListSelector`, you can bind the `Name` member to `Tag` property.

Comment: It is throwing  exception i.e  'AgHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\en-US\mscorlib.debug.resources.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
The program '[3520] AgHost.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).

Comment: Can you state what that exception is? You can look at that by adding a breakpoint before `Initialize()`

Comment: Karthik I succeed for TextBox and Image for LongListSelector controller. I am not using x:name like this. For above exception when the page navigates to LongListSelector page it has to show one textbox ,image and button. Everything is ok except button data binding.

Comment: Data binding a Name is technically possible, but is an extremely uncommon scenario because a data-bound `Name` cannot provide an identifier connection point for code-behind. Please try a different approach, since `MSDN` advises against that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18585238/how-to-bind-button-name-to-content